# Search Mongoid hash field by key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, search, mongoid

I thought this would be simple when I implemented it, however after much searching, googling and scanning of docs I can't seem to find an answer.

I have a field that is a hash where the keys are ids and the values are an array of other ids. For example:

```
{"52ab84929938c7f966d4f116"=>["52ab84919938c7f966d4ee7d"],
 "52ab84929938c7f966d4f117"=>["52ab84919938c7f966d4ee7d"],
 "52ab84929938c7f966d4f0cc"=>["52ab84919938c7f966d4ee7d", "52ab84929938c7f966d4f13d"],
 "52ab84929938c7f966d4f147"=>["52ab84919938c7f966d4ee7d"]}
```

This is probably better suited to a graph type db, but I'm unfamiliar with the technology and have already built the rest of my app around Mongoid. This was the simplest solution I could come up with for another complex problem.

So my question is how can I search for records that have, say, id:`52ab84929938c7f966d4f0cc` as the key in their hash field?

I tried doing it array style like so and got zero results returned:

```
Course.all_in(:skills_available => sk.id)
```

And I know this doesn't work, but it would be nice if it did:

```
Course.where(:skills_available.key => sk.id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Course.where(:'skills_available.52ab84929938c7f966d4f0cc'.ne => nil)
```

- Only restriction is that it will skip:  `{'52ab84929938c7f966d4f0cc' => nil}`

Comment: for people searching, `.ne` is mongoid `not equal`

Answer (score 1):

Technically Leszek answered my question correctly.

However, I soon realized I needed to be able to find all documents where that key was in an array of keys.

So for reference, here's the solution I wound up using:

```
jt = JobType.first
jt_skills = "['#{jt.skills_required.join("','")}']"
m = %Q{
  function() {
    found = false;
    keys = Object.keys(this.skills_available);
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      if(#{jt_skills}.indexOf(key) > 0) {
        found = true;
      }
    });
    if(found) {
      emit(this._id, keys);
    }
  }
}
r = %Q{
  function(key, values) { }
}
courses = Course.where(:skills_available.ne => {}).map_reduce(m,r).out(inline: true)
```

The second line converts the array into a string that can be passed into the JS map function. The JS map function checks every key in the skills_available hash to see if it is in the array of skills_required. And if it is, then that document is included. Finally the map_reduce is run on only courses where there are skills_available.